# Можно ли сказать "приючу у себя"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Где-то мне попалось обсуждение "правильно ли говорить "приючу". Пришли к выводу, что слово такое есть, но оно режет слух.
А действительно, есть ли слово "приючу (у себя)"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно. Словари дают такую форму как правильную и без ограничительных помет.